# QML, ScrollView and touch events on desktop

Tags: qt, qml

Since few months, directly in ListView item we can use ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {} to provide appropriate scrollbar. Unfortunately it doesn't behave natively for me so I decided to surround every ListView in the project with ScrollView and now it works fine except one thing:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
//import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  title: qsTr("Scroll")

  ScrollView {
    anchors.fill: parent

    ListView {
      anchors.fill: parent
      model: 20

      delegate: Text {
        text: "Item " + (index + 1)
        height: 50
        width: parent.width
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in the example above I cannot use touch event to scroll the view. I'm working on windows 10 and it doesn't matter if I use ScrollView that comes from QtQuick.Controls 1.4 or QtQuick.Controls 2.2 If I press and hold the mouse button, the view won't follow the mouse moves just like it does in case of ListView alone.

Is there any way to restore this behavior for this particular method of handling scrollbars?

Comment: The `anchors.fill: parent` on the ListView is a bad idea here. I've found that that will cause your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `Flickable { }` instead of `ScrollView`.

*** EDIT ***

`Flickable {}`  allows the user to scroll left and right using touch events such as flicking, dragging, etc.

It is designed for touch screens.  You use it the same way as a ScrollView {},  as a container class.

```
Flickable {


  anchors.fill: parent

        ListView {
          anchors.fill: parent
          model: 20
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add more detail in answer or leave this as a comment.